# Creating docker compose for Spring boot app with Mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to create a docker-compose file for my spring boot app that uses MongoDB atlas but when I sent a request it's not working locally.
when I am trying without docker it works fine locally.

in the logs, mongo is not making a connection

```
2021-07-02 10:05:38.867  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoAwsApplication      : Starting DemoAwsApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.10 on 08195c02d4c8 with PID 1 (/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes started by cnb in /workspace)
2021-07-02 10:05:38.873  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoAwsApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-07-02 10:05:40.170  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
2021-07-02 10:05:40.189  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-07-02 10:05:40.189  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-07-02 10:05:40.274  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-07-02 10:05:40.275  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1315 ms
2021-07-02 10:05:40.589  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-07-02 10:05:40.873  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with context path ''
2021-07-02 10:05:40.893  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoAwsApplication      : Started DemoAwsApplication in 2.845 seconds (JVM running for 3.37)
2021-07-02 10:20:37.316  INFO 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

hope someone can give me an example or guilds

docker-compose

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  app:
    image: idanovadia/demo-ecs:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 8080:5000
```

response

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-02T13:34:04.025+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/auth/signin"
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a container if you're using atlas?

Comment: I don't need a mongo container

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to define a port since you're using Atlas.

Remove => `spring.data.mongodb.port=27017`

And change the `uri` like below. You can only keep that in your `application.propertise`.

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://user:password@name.cvbdl.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: I did it but it not fix my issue

Comment: no
I change now my ports to 
ports:
      - 8080:5000

and got 404, but in the logs, I can see Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'